# Unexpected result from the COUNT syntax

Tags: sql

I would like to show the number of rows of two columns which belonging to two tables. However, the result is not I expected. I am really confused about that. Could you please advice? Thanks.

```
SELECT COUNT(TABLE1.INTEREST) FROM INCOME; // RESULT = 10

SELECT COUNT(TABLE2.LOAN) FROM EXPEND;  //RESULT = 10

SELECT COUNT(TABLE1.INTEREST), COUNT(TABLE2.LOAN) FROM INCOME, EXPEND;  //RESULT = 100
```

Why the result is "100|100" if I execute the third SQL command? I expect the result is "10|10".

Answer (score 2):

A [cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) is performed in your last query.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are joining every row of `INCOME` onto every row of `EXPEND` (called a cartesian product)

Instead of doing `FROM INCOME, EXPEND` you need to do something like

```
FROM INCOME
JOIN EXPEND
ON Income.SomeColumn = Expend.SomeColumn
```

or add a where clause to your current query:

```
FROM INCOME, EXPEND
WHERE Income.SomeColumn = Expend.SomeColumn
```